# How do i install Nvidia Drivers for GTX 850m On Arch-Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, nvidia

I am a linux beginner.running command lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)" brings up this result:
its seems that i am using the nouveau driver. i want to switch to the official drivers how do i do this.Also i am using x64 arch-linux on my laptop

[image]

Comment: You [read the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#Switching_between_NVIDIA_and_nouveau_drivers)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you using the laptop and you definitely want to use [Optimus](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html) technology for power savings. In this case, I strongly recommend you to use [bumblebee](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee).

Read bumblebee archwiki first.

I assuming that you have 64-bit architecture, so your next steps will be:

1) Delete all video drivers you currently have.

2) Install dependencies

```
sudo pacman -S bumblebee mesa xf86-video-intel nvidia lib32-virtualgl lib32-nvidia-utils lib32-mesa-libgl
```

3) Pick mesa-libgl if conflict. Pick xf86-input-libinput if conflict.

4) Add username to bumblebee group

```
gpasswd -a USER bumblebee
```

5) Enable bumblebee

```
sudo systemctl enable bumblebeed.service
```